# How do I get jQuery UI autocomplete multiple to remove items that have already been selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

The jQuery UI autocomplete multiple example provided [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple) allows you to add the same item more than once.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take the example provided by jQuery UI [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple), add the following line within the select function of the autocomplete:

```
availableTags.splice($.inArray(ui.item.value, availableTags), 1);
```

This basically removes the item that has just been selected from the list of available tags.

The select function you end up with should look like this:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    var terms = split( this.value );
    // remove the current input
    terms.pop();
    // add the selected item
    terms.push( ui.item.value );
    // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
    terms.push( "" );
    this.value = terms.join( ", " );
    // remove added item from list of available items to select
    availableTags.splice($.inArray(ui.item.value, availableTags), 1);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: it is helpful, +1 for you :)

Comment: what if I have availableTags coming from an ajax response inside Source: of auto complete ?